# Is it possible to specify the search path for a module in a python script? If it is, how do I do that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module-search-path

I have been coding in python for about 2 months, but I'm only familiar with basic object-oriented programming, so I do not really understand things like how searching for modules is implemented. (Basically I'm a noob.)

I pip installed a package called Opentrons [Opentrons 2.5.2](https://pypi.org/project/opentrons/2.5.2/) and all its dependencies into the samefolder as a python script I'm currently writing. However when I tried to import the module below[1], I get an error saying that "Opentrons is not a module". Then, I tried shifting it into the python library because I found out the search path using the pprint module and it seems to work. I was wondering if I can specify the search path from the .py file itself instead of manually printing the search path and putting the file into the library that the script searches for. (Willing to put in images of the directories I put the opentrons package in if it helps.)

[1]

```py
import sys
import pprint
pprint.pprint(search.path)
from opentrons import robot, containers, instruments
```

Edit: I realise that the fact that I am running all my scripts in a Spyder console located in a python 3.6 environment might be important.

Comment: in code you can add folder to `sys.path` before you import - `sys.path.append("full/path/to/folder")`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `__import__` function, or [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html). This should allow you to specify the path.